# Why doesn't it clash when both divs are set to float:left?

Tags: html, css, css-float

```
<div class="header">

<div class="contact half">
    <dl>
        <dt>Email</dt>
        <dd>z@srgbethet.com</dt>

        <dt>Phone</dt>
        <dd>+456 333 444</dd>

        <dt>Website</dt>
        <dd>kkkk.com</dd>
    </dl>
</div>

<div class="skills half">
    <ul>
        <li>Quantum Accelerators</li>
        <li>dfeerfbe</li>
        <li>Parachuting</li>
        <li>Photon Cannons</li>
    </ul>
</div> 
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.half {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 }
```

The end result was that both the contact `div` and the skills `div` were nicely fitted side by side. Why didn't it clash since both were following the `float:left` property ?

Comment: what you want to achieve

Comment: cant understand your question, what you want exactly

Comment: Don't people understand the meaning of "why"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you apply `float:left` to an element, the following block element will sit to the right of it (unless otherwise stated).

The fact they both have `float:left` is irrelevant, its just because your first element, `contact half`, has `float:left`

In this jsfiddle example I've created, I've removed `half` from the 2nd element, and they still sit side by side:

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/nV5Sx/

If you don't want them to sit side by side, you can `clear:left` the 2nd element:

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/nV5Sx/1/

I get the impression you could do with learning more about how `float:left` works. See this handy tutorial for more information on this styling property:

http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the definition of float property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_cssfloat.asp)
Float is used to align objects horizontally, hence it didn't conflicted. Though you have used same class for two elements it doesn't matter for HTML DOM.